# (A-Frame) How to stop a object intersect with cursor?

Tags: aframe

I use a-frame to do web-vr. I's good to use but I have some situation don't know how to implement.
First I put a Camera with cursor and set the raycaster intersect with object ".trigger".

`<a-entity camera="" look-controls="" position="" rotation="" scale="" visible="">
                        <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 1500" position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03" material="color: cyan; shader: flat" raycaster="objects: .trigger" rotation="" scale="" visible="">
                            <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="forwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1" dur="150"></a-animation>
                            <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="backwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1" dur="1500"></a-animation>
                        </a-entity>
                    </a-entity>`

And create a entity with class "trigger".

`<a-entity class="tigger" id="clip01" clip01="on: click; conditionId: ShowClipTrigger" data-is-trigger="true" geometry="primitive: plane; width: 2; height: 3" material=" src: #clip01-pic; opacity: 0.99;" position="-5.913 -3.544 4.675" rotation="-82.048 122.222 11.345" scale="" visible="" animation__move="" animation__rotate=""></a-entity>`

The ".trigger" object will trigger some action after on click event received. My question is how to disable the intersect after the trigger been click. I try remove the class "trigger" from the object after the click evnet, but it still can intersect with cursor.

I search the a-frame document [raycaster](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/raycaster.html#properties) but no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the whitelisted class, You need to refresh the raycaster:

```
var raycasterEl = AFRAME.scenes[0].querySelector('[raycaster]');
raycasterEl.components.raycaster.refreshObjects();
```

Also You can achieve this by making a simple switch in the event listener:

```
 var switch=true;
 el.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    if(switch){
      //doStuff
      switch = false;
    }
 });
```

or remove the listener completely, like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dhmafL7c/):

```
//listener
this.doStuff = this.doStuff.bind(this);
el.addEventListener("click", this.doStuff());
//function
doStuff: function(){
this.el.removeEventListener("click",this.doStuff);
}
```

Comment: I don't want the cursor has any interaction with the trigger, so the first answer is what I need! Thanks!

Comment: glad I could help :)